# How to set default browser size with Capybara + Selenium + Firefox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, capybara

Looking at https://gist.github.com/mars/6957187#gistcomment-3019727 and several other places, it appears that the way to change the default options is to overwrite the driver registration with your own code. Here's my driver registration:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium_headless do |app|
    version = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.load_selenium
    options_key = Capybara::Selenium::Driver::CAPS_VERSION.satisfied_by?(version) ? :capabilities : :options
    browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new.tap do |opts|
      opts.add_argument '-headless'
      opts.add_argument '--window-size=1920,1080'
    end
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, **{ :browser => :firefox, options_key => browser_options })
  end
end
```

I know this is working, as the window size is clearly being passed to Firefox:

```
root        1466    1449  0 00:47 pts/5    00:00:00 /root/.webdrivers/geckodriver --port=4444 --binary=/usr/bin/firefox
root        1469    1466  1 00:47 pts/5    00:00:04 firefox-esr --marionette -headless --window-size=1920,1080 -foreground -no-remote -profile /tmp/rust_mozprofileAPMJOb
```

But, when I interrupt my tests and then use `save_and_open_screenshot`, the browser is definitely NOT 1920x1080:

```
General
Complete name                            : capybara-202106300047373170133175.png
Format                                   : PNG
Format/Info                              : Portable Network Graphic
File size                                : 45.1 KiB

Image
Format                                   : PNG
Format/Info                              : Portable Network Graphic
Format_Compression                       : Deflate
Width                                    : 1 366 pixels
Height                                   : 694 pixels
Color space                              : RGBA
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossless
Stream size                              : 45.1 KiB (100%)
```

I'm not sure why the browser appears to be the wrong size. If I manually resize the page, the resulting saved image works fine:

```
[9] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::TheUserLoginAndAvatarArea::ClickingTheDropdownForTheUserProfile>)> page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1920,1080)
=> {"x"=>0, "y"=>0, "width"=>1920, "height"=>1080}
```

But the whole point is to not have to do this.

I've seen several examples of using `resize_to` in a `before`, but that's also not optimal.

Any thoughts on why this doesn't work as expected?

**Edit:**
It actually works with Chromium:

```
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_headless do |app|
    version = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.load_selenium
    options_key = Capybara::Selenium::Driver::CAPS_VERSION.satisfied_by?(version) ? :capabilities : :options
    browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new.tap do |opts|
      opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
      opts.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
      opts.add_argument('--headless')
      opts.add_argument('--disable-gpu') if Gem.win_platform?
      # Workaround https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2650&q=load&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary
      opts.add_argument('--disable-site-isolation-trials')
    end
  
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, **{ :browser => :chrome, options_key => browser_options })
  end
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for manually saving the screenshot? You can always use `driver.save_screenshot("image1.png")` to capture the screen in registered browser size.

Comment: The goal isn't the screenshot. The goal is fixing the browser size. But it's good to know I can save screenshots that way, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe for the Firefox options the argument names are slightly different and you can achieve the smaller browser size this way:

```
Capybara.register_driver :mobile_driver_without_ui do |app|
  browser_options =
    ::Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new.tap do |opts|
      opts.add_argument('--width=335')
      opts.add_argument('--height=1080')
      opts.add_argument('--headless')
    end

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, options: browser_options)
end
```

This helped me figure this out https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1354#issuecomment-413552319